# Google Calendar: get date of event?

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

I'm wondering if I can access to the date of every event of Google Calendar with JAVA using Gdata Api. I checked the library of api but there's no field in IEntry Class represent the date of events. Please let me know if anyone has any idea. thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the getEntry() method on the EventEntry:

http://www.google.com/codesearch#EOYaOg_yTgg/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/model/gd/EventEntry.java&q=addtime%20package:http://gdata-java-client%5C.googlecode%5C.com&type=cs&l=439